# Why do I get 'Error opening login file' when trying to make a login for my project with two sign-up modes?

Tags: c

I'm working on a C program using Replit on Windows, and I'm encountering an error when trying to open a login file. I'm getting the error message "Error opening login file" when attempting to read the file. I believe I have followed the correct steps, but I'm still facing this issue.

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct{
char name[50];
char lname[50];
char id[50];
char password[50];
int isSignedIn;
int mode;
 }Login; 


void logorsignin(Login *a, int mode) {
    int login;
    char id[50];
    char password[50];
    char name[50];
    char lname[50];
    char sid[50];
    char spassword[50];
    int r = 0;
    int choix;

    printf("\nHello\n");
    printf("1. Login\n");
    printf("2. Sign up\n");
    printf("3. Back\n");
    scanf("%d", &login);

    switch (login) {
        case 1:
            printf("What is your id?\n");
            scanf("%s", id);
            printf("What is your password?\n");
            scanf("%s", password);
            FILE *fichier_login;

            if (mode == 1) {
            fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordManagement.txt", "r");
             }
            else if (mode == 2) {
            fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordBuying.txt", "r");
            }


            if (fichier_login == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening login file.\n");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                while (fscanf(fichier_login, "%s %s %s %s", a->name, a->lname, a->id, a->password) != EOF) {
                    if (strcmp(id, a->id) == 0 && strcmp(password, a->password) == 0) {
                        printf("You are connected\n");
                        r = 1;
                        a->isSignedIn = 1;
                        a->mode = mode;  // Store the chosen mode in the Login struct
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (r != 1) {
                    printf("Your id or your password is incorrect\n");
                    a->isSignedIn = 0;
                }
            }
            fclose(fichier_login);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("What is your first name?\n");
            scanf("%s", name);
            printf("What is your last name?\n");
            scanf("%s", lname);
            printf("Choose an id\n");
            scanf("%s", sid);
            printf("Choose a password\n");
            scanf("%s", spassword);

            // Ask for the mode during sign-up
            printf("Choose your mode:\n");
            printf("1. Management\n");
            printf("2. Buying\n");
            scanf("%d", &mode);

            FILE *fichier_signup;

            if (mode == 1) {
                fichier_signup = fopen("idandpasswordManagement.txt", "a");
            } else if (mode == 2) {
                fichier_signup = fopen("idandpasswordBuying.txt", "a");
            }

            if (fichier_signup == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening signup file.\n");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                fprintf(fichier_signup, "\n%s %s %s %s", name, lname, sid, spassword);
                fclose(fichier_signup);
                a->isSignedIn = 1;
                printf("Sign up successful. You are now signed in.\n");
                a->mode = mode;  // Store the chosen mode in the Login struct
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Going back...\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("Error: Choose a correct option.\n");
            break;
    }
}



int main(void) {
    int choice;
    printf("\n WELCOME TO UTOPIA !\n\n");
    Login a;
    logorsignin(&a,a.mode);

    if (a.isSignedIn == 1) {
        if (a.mode == 1) {
            // Management mode
            printf("MANAGEMENT");
        } else if (a.mode == 2) {
            // Buying mode
            printf("BUYING");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

n the logorsignin function, I'm trying to open the login file for reading using the fopen function. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
FILE *fichier_login;

if (mode == 1) {
    fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordManagement.txt", "r");
} else if (mode == 2) {
    fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordBuying.txt", "r");
}

if (fichier_login == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening login file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

i tried some debugg statements like :

```
FILE *fichier_login;

if (mode == 1) {
    printf("Opening login file (idandpasswordManagement.txt)...\n");
    fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordManagement.txt", "r");
    if (fichier_login == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening login file (idandpasswordManagement.txt).\n");
        exit(1);
    }
} else if (mode == 2) {
    printf("Opening login file (idandpasswordBuying.txt)...\n");
    fichier_login = fopen("idandpasswordBuying.txt", "r");
    if (fichier_login == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening login file (idandpasswordBuying.txt).\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or insights on why I might be encountering this error and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The file is probably not in your current directory. Try using a full pathname to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, you have:

```
Login a;
logorsignin(&a,a.mode);
```

where `a` is uninitialized and it's contents are indeterminate.

The following checks in `logorsignin()`:

```
if (mode == 1)
...
else if (mode == 2)
```

invoke undefined behaviour because the value of `a.mode` which was passed an argument was indeterminate.

I'm unaware whether `errno` is set on `fopen()` failure on Windows, but it'd be worth a try. Change:

```
printf("Error opening login file.\n");
```

to:

```
perror ("fopen():");

// Or

fprintf (stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror (errno));
```